# Logic or meaning of $5 \equiv \frac{4}{8}\pmod {12}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

In modular division, what is the meaning that *should* be ascribed to the notation exemplified below (also given on p. 5 of [this](http://www2.sunysuffolk.edu/fultonj/MA22/Modular%20Arithmetic%20&%20Cryptography.pdf))?

$$\begin{align}
\implies & 5\cdot8 \equiv 4\pmod {12} \tag{i} \\[2ex]
\implies & 5 \equiv \frac{4}{8}\pmod {12} \tag{ii} \\[2ex]
\implies & 8 \equiv \frac{4}{5}\pmod {12} \tag{iii}
\end{align}$$

I think in terms of values reached by different residue classes, but I am unable to get any clue. 
As a very simple example,
 values taken by $4 \pmod{12}$ residue class are: $4, 16, 28, 40$
values taken by $5 \pmod{12}$ residue class are: $5, 17, 29, 41$
values taken by $8 \pmod{12}$ residue class are: $8, 20, 32, 44$

This lends no meaning to eqns. $\text{(ii), (iii)}$ above.

Comment: $a\equiv b\pmod n\implies n\mid(a-b)$

Comment: But, if I break into components, as $40$ into $5,8$ then how to apply say as in eqn.(ii) or eqn.(iii), so as to find any logic for equivalence class of $5, 8$. It is okay that $40 \equiv 4\pmod{12}$, but it does not make any logic on breaking $40$ further.

Comment: you cannot just divide by integers on both sides of a congruence relation. See that $12$ divides $5-\frac48$ doesnt make any sense.

Comment: @Abishanka Saha I have copied example from page 5 of http://www2.sunysuffolk.edu/fultonj/MA22/Modular%20Arithmetic%20&%20Cryptography.pdf.

Comment: Note that $5*8 \equiv 2*8$. You cannot divide modulo $12$.

Comment: @mr_e_man It makes a very tangible case to prove lack of logic, but why the source stated (in edited OP) gave this is not clear at all.

Comment: You can label equations by using `\tag{#}`

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Thanks for that, it would help a lot.

Comment: @jiten you can go back in and make edits.

Comment: @Chase Ryan Taylor  Done it, but need spacing to be equally aligned so had to remove $\implies$. Any clue.

Comment: @jiten Try using the `\align` environment and `\cdot` instead of `*`. You can read all about it in the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr).

Comment: @Chase Ryan Taylor  Hope I am correct in implementing align environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71754/discussion-between-chase-ryan-taylor-and-jiten).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- $5 \cdot 5 =25 \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$ so the multiplicative inverse of $5 \bmod 12\,$ is $5^{-1}=5$.

  Therefore $5 \cdot 8 \equiv 4 \implies 5^{-1}\cdot5\cdot8 \equiv 5^{-1} \cdot 4 \implies 8 \equiv 5^{-1}\cdot 4 \pmod{12}\,$. The latter may sometimes be written as $8 \equiv \frac{4}{5} \pmod{12}\,$ but that's arguably an abuse of notation, unless such notation was very explicitly and narrowly defined before being used.
- $8$ has no multiplicative inverse $\bmod 12$, so $5 \equiv \frac{4}{8} \pmod{12}$ makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: On page #7, the author of the source states two types of divisions - (1) Which have no answer (for us I feel the correct word is: logic, meaning), (2) Which have an answer. The author further states :"Even seemingly odd divisions like $\frac{0}{3}$ or even worse $\frac{0}{0}$ are legal $\mod 6$. Both have the answer $2$. Explain this?"

Comment: @jiten Indeed, quoting from the book: "*Unlike the division of real numbers, mod division does not always yield an answer*". IMHO that's a rather odd and un-pedagogical way to "*define*" an operator, but which "*does not always yield an answer*".

Comment: So, the author states it to be 'odd' but still legal.

Comment: @jiten For certain fuzzy values of "*legal*", I guess ;-) The focus of the text looks to be more computational than mathematical, so I guess some liberties are to be expected, but can still be confusing if you are reading it with a math-oriented eye.

Comment: Okay, I will be having that into view.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $3*8=24\equiv 0\pmod{12}$. Adding this equation to your equation $(i)$ yields $5*8\equiv 8*8=4\pmod{12}$. So we will get $\frac48\equiv5$ as well as  $\frac48\equiv8$ (both mod 12) which is nonsensical (that is not well-defined).

So one should avoid assigning any meaning to division by something which is a zero divisor.

When operating modulo a given $m$, if we stick to $b$ with gcd$(b,m)=1$ all zero divisors will be avoided and fractions with such $b$ in the denominators will be meaningful (will have unique value).

Comment: I hope you are also answering my comments to @dxiv answer, as you referred to division by $0$.

Comment: Not clear in which situation should stick to $b$ with $\gcd(b,m) =1$ for modulo arithmetic, it happens never; all values are used up.

Comment: If you want to put $b$ in the denominator of a fraction, then  the fraction will be meaningful (unique-valued) only when gcd$(b,m)=1$.